# Is there a way to tell how a previously closed question was reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

I came across this question:

[Did God create man to replace the fallen Angels?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19821/did-god-create-man-to-replace-the-fallen-angels)

I quickly went to vote to close only to find that I already had some time ago.

I can see two possibilities:

1. The close votes never reached 5 and then expired.
2. It was closed but later reopened.

For circumstance two, I want to see who voted to reopen and when. How can I do that?

For both circumstances, what were you thinking, community? Why is this not closed?

Comment: Seems to me it's a case of [Why does God...?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/why-does-god?cb=1) and ought to be closed.

Comment: @Flimzy Exactly, but something happened. Apparently my close vote, along with others, maybe, expired, because the five needed was never met. Feel free to vtc if you think it needs it. You probably already did. I see it has 2 votes already.

Answer (score 4):

The edit history of the question will show close/open details ifany exist. If they don't register in there it must not have been closed.

Comment: Thanks. So circumstance 1 is what happened. What about my second question? Should this be closed or remain open?

Comment: Sorry haven't had time to review it and it seems border-line from first glance so I want to think about it properly before acting...

Comment: No problem. It's already generated three votes since my post here on meta.